SQL not returning week hours properly
I have created SQL to calculate the 12 hours window, for the weekend. But the problem is it returns the hours correctly till Saturday but not on Sundays.
The query filters for rows where the date falls within a 12-hour window, starting 153 hours after the day following the Starting and ending 165 hours. But when I execute for Sunday, the current week Monday do not come instead next week's Monday come. How do I correct it. Since today is 16-June-2024 but it returns 17-June -2024.
SET DATEFIRST 1;

WITH Current AS 
(
    SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS Starting
)
SELECT 
    [Date], [priority], [Account]
FROM
    [table_1]
WHERE 
    Date >= (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 153, DATEADD(DAY, 1, Starting))
             FROM Current)
    AND Date <= (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 165, DATEADD(DAY, 1, Starting))
                 FROM Current)
    AND priority = 'P1'


Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

BLUF: Depending on your SQL Server version, you can try either SELECT DATETRUNC(week, GETDATE()) AS Starting (2022 or later) or SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) / 7, 0) AS Starting (earlier versions).
Per the DATEDIFF documentation, "Specifying SET DATEFIRST has no effect on DATEDIFF. DATEDIFF always uses Sunday as the first day of the week to ensure the function operates in a deterministic way."
If you are running SQL Server 2022 or later, you can use the DATETRUNC(week, ) function to accomplish what you want. This function respects the DATEFIRST setting.
For earlier versions, you need to calculate using day calculations relative to a specific reference date. For Monday, you can use 0, which is equivalent to '1900-01-01` (a Monday).
DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, D.Dt) / 7, 0)  -- 0 = 1900-01-01 = Monday
or
DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, D.Dt) / 7 * 7, 0)

For the general case that respects the DATEFIRST setting, the following can be used:
DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, @@DATEFIRST - 1, D.Dt) / 7, @@DATEFIRST - 1)
or
DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, @@DATEFIRST - 1, D.Dt) / 7 * 7, @@DATEFIRST - 1)

Sample code:
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Monday

SELECT
    D.Dt,
    DATENAME(weekday, D.Dt) AS DoW,
    DATEPART(week, D.Dt) AS Week,
    DATETRUNC(week, D.Dt) AS Good, -- 2022 only
    CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, D.Dt), 0)) AS Bad,
    CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, D.Dt) / 7, 0)) AS Good1,
    CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, D.Dt) / 7 * 7, 0)) AS Good2,
    CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, @@DATEFIRST - 1, D.Dt) / 7, @@DATEFIRST - 1)) AS Good3,
    CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, @@DATEFIRST - 1, D.Dt) / 7 * 7, @@DATEFIRST - 1)) AS Good4
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, 20) S
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(day, S.value, '20240101')) AS Dt) D

Results:



Dt
DoW
Week
Good (and Good1..4)
Bad




2024-01-01
Monday
1
2024-01-01
2024-01-01


2024-01-02
Tuesday
1
2024-01-01
2024-01-01


2024-01-03
Wednesday
1
2024-01-01
2024-01-01


2024-01-04
Thursday
1
2024-01-01
2024-01-01


2024-01-05
Friday
1
2024-01-01
2024-01-01


2024-01-06
Saturday
1
2024-01-01
2024-01-01


2024-01-07
Sunday
1
2024-01-01
2024-01-08


2024-01-08
Monday
2
2024-01-08
2024-01-08


2024-01-09
Tuesday
2
2024-01-08
2024-01-08


2024-01-10
Wednesday
2
2024-01-08
2024-01-08


2024-01-11
Thursday
2
2024-01-08
2024-01-08


2024-01-12
Friday
2
2024-01-08
2024-01-08


2024-01-13
Saturday
2
2024-01-08
2024-01-08


2024-01-14
Sunday
2
2024-01-08
2024-01-15


2024-01-15
Monday
3
2024-01-15
2024-01-15


2024-01-16
Tuesday
3
2024-01-15
2024-01-15


2024-01-17
Wednesday
3
2024-01-15
2024-01-15


2024-01-18
Thursday
3
2024-01-15
2024-01-15


2024-01-19
Friday
3
2024-01-15
2024-01-15


2024-01-20
Saturday
3
2024-01-15
2024-01-15


2024-01-21
Sunday
3
2024-01-15
2024-01-22



See this db<>fiddle for a demo that also includes cases for other DATEFIRST settings.
